# Parent variables dissappear after child errors on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models User, Dad, Mom and Kid.

```
class Dad
 has_many :kids
end

class Mom
 has_many :kids
end

class User
 has_many :kids
end

class Kid
 belongs_to :mom
 belongs_to :dad
 belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to create a new Kid inside of the Dad and Mom.

```
resources :dads
 resources :moms
   resources :kids
 end
end

dads/1/moms/1/kids/new

# KidsController
def new
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
  @mom = Mom.find(params[:mom_id])
  @kid = Kid.new
end

def create
  @kid = current_user.kids.build(kid_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @kid.save
     format.html { redirect_to @kid, notice: 'Kid was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @kid }
    else
     format.html { render action: 'new' }
     format.json { render json: @kid.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

In my view I have the variables `@dad.name` and `@mom.name` but when an error happens when creating a kid, I get:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

And I believe this to be because of me not having:

```
@dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
@mom = Mom.find(params[:mom_id])
```

In the `create` action but that doesn't work either.

```
Couldn't find Dad without an ID
```

So how would I correct this?

**EDIT**

Here's my view.

```
Kids/new.html.erb

<% provide(:title, "Adding New Kid for #{@dad.name.titleize} and #{@mom.name.titleize}") %>
<% page_header "Adding New Kid for #{@dad.name.titleize} and #{@mom.name.titleize}" %>

<%= form_for @kid do |f| %>
  # kid fields
<% end %>
```

And how I get the `provide` and `page_header`.

```
ApplicationHelper

def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Kid Zone"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end

def page_header(page_title)
  content_for(:page_header) { page_title }
end
```

shared/page_header.html.erb

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h3><%= yield(:page_header) %></h3>
</div>
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<head>
   <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
</head>
```

**Answer**

Had to make my `kid` form be:

```
 <%= form_for [@dad, @mom, @kid] do |f| %>
      # kid fields
 <% end %>
```

and add to the `create` action just like my `new` action:

```
@dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
@mom = Mom.find(params[:mom_id])
```

Comment: Don't you need to assign `@mom` and `@dad` to `Kid.new`? Something like `@kid.mom = @mom` and `@kid.dad = @dad`?

Comment: @UriAgassi In order to show `@dad.name` in the view? I don't think so. Since I'm inside of the Dad and mom I want to create the kid at. In conclusion though, I don't know. That's why I'm looking for help.

Comment: Your problem is in `new` or in `create`?

Comment: @UriAgassi I can't really say I just know after you do a POST it goes to `/kids`. That's where the problem comes in. Which I think is in `create`.

Comment: You should make `@mom` and `@dad` available in the `create` view too. Maybe try it and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: That's because when you create `@kid`, you never say that `@mom` and `@dad` are _his_ parents - they could be just a couple across the street. By the time `@kid` reaches `create` - `@mom` and `@dad` are gone (with their ids)... Set the references inside `@kid`, and see if it works...

Comment: @user2784630 did you change your routes?

Comment: @user2784630 share your view.

Comment: @Babar I added my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edited Answer

Since everything else is in order, and with the added information of your form, you need to create your form for nested resource like everything else in your app. so when it fails you will not lose information.

```
<%= form_for [@dad,@mom,@kid] do |f| %>
  # kid fields
<% end %>
```

and definitely you will find `@dad` and `@mom` in your `create` function as specified by `Uri Aggasi`

Comment: How exactly does the resolve the problem? Do you mind clarifying those details for the person asking the question?

Comment: Follow this [Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and read 2.7 Nested Resources

Comment: I'm familiar with rails, I use it daily. I didn't ask you what your question was doing, I asked how does it solve the problem?

Comment: the route he created is nested and if an error occurs without the nested routing he will lose the info of where the link goes back to(parameter will be lost). this way after error it will render same url 'root/dad/1/mom/1/kid/new' instead of 'root/kids/new'

Comment: The OP Has listed the same routing structure you instruct him to implement. That is why I'm asking you how this solves his problem.

Comment: his route file doesn't have the 'do'.

Comment: @Babar Thanks this got it working after adding to the `create` action: `@dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])` and `@mom = Mom.find(params[:mom_id])`

Answer (score 1):

When you create `@kid`, you never say that `@mom` and `@dad` are his parents - they could be just a couple across the street. By the time `@kid` reaches create - `@mom` and `@dad` are gone (with their ids).

Therefore you need to assign `@kid.mom` and `@kid.dad` in the `new` action before rendering the view:

```
def new
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
  @mom = Mom.find(params[:mom_id])
  @kid = Kid.new
  @kid.mom = @mom
  @kid.dad = @dad
end
```

Comment: I added my view for more clarity EDIT.

Comment: Your `# kid_fields` contain `mom_id` and `dad_id`?